# Or operator vs. Ternary operator

Tags: javascript, performance, logical-operators

Which piece of code is faster, or just better?

---

**Ternary operator**

```
action = typeMap[type] ? typeMap[type] : typeMap['default'];
```

---

**Or operator**

```
action = typeMap[type] || typeMap['default']
```

---

Thank you!

Comment: [Race the horses](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: They have a difference.

Comment: http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/82593/javascript-ternary-operator-vs

Comment: @Sayse interesting link!

Comment: @Sayse Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Speed is not the issue here, they are equally fast and none of them can cause a bottleneck in your code flow. They have a slightly different behaviour while checking condition though.

The real question here is: **which one is more readable**? If someone (or yourself) would read this code, which one would be more understandable?

Even if it may not be elegant, maybe a solution like the following in some cases could be better

```
var action = typeMap['default'];
if (typeMap[type]) {
    action = typeMap[type];
}
```

This solution also allows you to do a more precise check on the codition, given that the truth table in javascript may be tricky.

I'm not saying this solution is better, just consider which one is more readable in your situation.

Comment: I think you are right. Thank you so much.

Comment: I was completely wrong, tested it with different values, still same result.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I actually didn't test your answer. Anyway, thank you for sharing.